# How to refresh widget?

Tags: flutter

I want to "refresh" my widget after i upload a file.

```
new Container(
      child: _profileAvatar(),
      width: 150.0,
       height: 150.0,
),

Widget _profileAvatar(){
  if(!hasProfilImage){
    return CircleAvatar(
      radius: 30.0,
      backgroundImage:
      new ExactAssetImage('assets/images/default_profile.png'),
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    );
  }else {
    return CircleAvatar(
      radius: 30.0,
      backgroundImage:
      NetworkImage( "${Configuration.url}assets/profileImage/${userProfilImage}"),
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    );
  }
}
```

and here is how i upload a file

```
Future getImage() async {
    var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    setState(() {
      if(image != null) {
        _image = image;
        hasProfilImage = true;
        _upload();
      }
    });
  }
```

for now after the upload process finished, i need to re open this "page" to see the new image.

How can i show the new image immediately after the upload process finish?
thanks in advance

Here is what i try so far , but still no help

```
  Future getImage() async {
    var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    setState(() {
      if(image != null) {
        _image = image;
        _upload().then((isSuccess){
          setState(() {
            hasProfilImage = true;
          });
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

here is my full script https://pastebin.com/59UfYa2P

Answer (score 0):

Your Upload function probably returns a Future with some value whether the image is successfully uploaded or not.

```
Future getImage() async {
var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
  if(image != null) {
    _image = image;
    _upload().then((isSuccess){
      // once upload is completed then, call setState and it will rebuild the widget tree and update the view.
      setState(() {
        hasProfilImage = true;
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: so i need to call the widget inside the setState ?

Comment: no, calling the `setState(() {})` automatically rebuild the widgets and which will update your image on UI. You don't need to add code inside `setState(() {})`

Comment: have you check my updated question?, is that what you mean?

Comment: check my edited answer. You should not be calling a method inside `setState`. you should call that method and wait for the response and then call `setState`.

Comment: i already try it but it is not working. https://gist.github.com/bobykurniawan11/2fcb05b25ec02e7d03ac5639dc3de05b

Answer (score 0):

As you are working with flutter you can use `StatefulWidget` which has a `setState` method. whenever you want to update the data put that data after processing. It will automatically update at its position.

> setState(() {});

If you have the API call or function in another widget you can use `callback` to update the widget.

If you want to update the previous widget after the processing the on the next widget Here is the callback

```
_navigateAndDisplayDriverSelection(
  BuildContext context, String userId, String driveId) async {


final driverModal = await Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => Drivers(userId: userId, driveId: driveId)),
);

setState(() {});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to pass down your setState method through your widget tree, you can also use ScopedModels.

This page has a brief example of how to implement a scopedmodel:
https://pub.dev/packages/scoped_model

Just know that every time you call notifylisteners(), everything underneath ScopedModelDescendant gets rebuild.

The issue you are facing is one of state-management, and there are also alternative solutions for this problem: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt